# Sails.js: services function called two times

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

Just started how sails.js `services` works but  i got services function called two times

here is my **service.js**

```
module.exports = {
    getuserFavouriteArray:function (callback) {
        return callback('ok from service');
    }
}
```

And i called this service from my controller

```
FavouriteService.getuserFavouriteArray(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
```

It works fine however i got the `console.log(response);` message two times

```
ok from service
ok from service
```

**UPDATE**

Going deeply into the problem finally found its not the problem with services its because of controller executes multiple times so i hide all the routes in my `route.js` and test with a single route  but still i got controller execute twice.

```
function (req,res) {


        var sql = "SELECT a.title,a.image_name,a.id as art_id,COUNT(b.art_id) AS 'total_comments',COUNT(d.art_id) as total_favourite,a.base_price, a.total_share,CONCAT(c.first_name,' ',c.last_name) as artist_name FROM cushbu_art a LEFT JOIN cushbu_art_comments b ON a.id = b.art_id LEFT JOIN cushbu_mark_user_favorites d ON a.id = d.art_id LEFT JOIN cushbu_users c ON a.artist_id=c.id  WHERE  a.status=$1 AND a.category=$2 GROUP BY a.id";
        sequelize.query(sql,{bind:[1,req.param('category')],type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}).then(function (art) {

            FavouriteService.getuserFavouriteArray(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });


            res.view('arts/list-art-with-category',{'arts':art,category:req.param('category')});
        }).catch(function (err) {

            res.json({
                'status':false,
                'message':'An unexpected error in DB',
                'err':err
            })
        })

    }
```

**Route**

```
GET /:category': {controller:'ArtlistController',action:'breadCumbsCategory'}
```

Comment: I tried what you said above with a new service file and controller file but couldnt replicate it. I got the log only once in the console. Can you elaborate a little more? Maybe provide your complete code where you use this controller and method with route etc.

Comment: Also i tested with single route and it still execute multiple times

Comment: Does your controller method take a long time to execute? (before responding). If so, browsers may try a second time, and retrigger the method.

Comment: Another thought, is this triggered by form submission? Might you be accidentally submitting twice (ex once auto done by the form html, and once with ajax or something)

Comment: It's not a form submit also method doesn't make too much time

Comment: I'll take one more shot... `/:category` is a pretty broad route! Is there a chance that it is catching requests for resources (like css or js files, images, fonts, etc)?

Comment: Thanks for the catch let me check it

Comment: thanks for pointing that issue its solved however it happens again when controller takes too much time to execute.

Comment: Actually  that function  do a file uploading to AWS s3 (size>20MB  upt to 100MB) normally it takes more than 4 minutes at that time controller execute twice

Comment: For a long upload, the solution is often to send back a response from the controller method *before* the upload is complete. That's complicated though, it means that having the webpage react when upload is finished will be hard - involving sockets or sails.io or something. But for starters remember that calling `res.send(...)` does not halt execution, you can perform the heavy work of the upload after that in the controller.

Comment: I am doing the same method here but there is no socket .Just update the dB and send mail when upload finished.

Comment: Controller send an immediate response and do upload in background